# How can Spinraza be effective on peripheral motor neurons outside of the spinal cord if it cannot penetrate the blood-brain barrier?

Tags: medications

I have SMA type 3. I had four intrathecal Nusinersen injections but I had no noticable improvement. I have doubts about its effectiveness outside of spinal cord, because we know that Spinraza can not permeate BBB.

How can Spinraza be effective on peripheral motor neurons outside of the spinal cord if it cannot penetrate the blood-brain barrier?

Comment: Peripheral motor neurons are not in the brain, therefore the BBB doesn't apply to them.

Comment: @CareyGregory I didn't get what you mean. I know where are the peripheral neurons. I had four intrathecal nusinersen injections.

Comment: The spinal cord isn't protected by the BBB. It's protected by the blood–spinal cord barrier, which is physiologically different than the BBB.

Comment: I’ll try to work on an answer here, but the clue is the route of administration - it’s not injected into your blood so the blood-brain barrier does not apply.

Comment: @CareyGregory Thank you for responding. `The blood-spinal cord barrier (BSCB) is the functional equivalent of the blood-brain barrier (BBB) in the sense of providing a specialized microenvironment for the cellular constituents of the spinal cord.` 
`In clinical practice, nusinersen is administered intrathecally because it does not cross the blood-brain barrier and therefore cannot be targeted to the CNS following subcutaneous or intravenous administration.`

Comment: @CareyGregory Peripheral motor neurons are located inside the central nervous system, which extends to the dorsal and ventral roots of the spinal cord. Blood can not easily reach the stroma (all cellular compartments) of the spinal cord due to the BBB/BSCB, but importantly there is no barrier between the cerebrospinal fluid and the stroma (which includes the motoneurons affected in SMA). Intrathecal administrations mean that the drug is directly injected into the cerebrospinal fluid (usually via the ventricles or cisterna magna or lumbar puncture) and can freely diffuse into the motoneurons.

Answer (score 3):

[Spinraza (Nusinersen)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nusinersen) is injected directly into the cerebrospinal fluid adjacent to the spinal cord (intrathecal) where it diffuses freely into the spinal cord. Its mechanism of action is to replace a missing protein through alternative splicing (quoting from the same Wikipedia article):

> Nusinersen modulates alternative splicing of the SMN2 gene, functionally converting it into SMN1 gene, thus increasing the level of SMN protein in the CNS.

That means the drug needs to be where RNA is formed and spliced: the nucleus of the cell, found at the cell body. The cell bodies of [motor neurons](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motor_neuron) that project to muscles are also located in the spinal cord.

So, the drug is injected right to the compartment where it's active. No blood brain barrier to cross. It wouldn't do anything useful for motor neurons peripherally because the peripheral part of the cell isn't the part of the cell where the drug is active. The muscle cells peripherally are also not a direct target of the drug.

The forms of SMA that are treated by Nusinersen/Spinraza involve the death of spinal motor neurons that lack functional [SMN protein](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survival_of_motor_neuron). I do not believe these drugs are expected or intended to reverse SMA symptoms; rather, they prevent further death of these cells and therefore prevent progression of the disease.

Comment: Thank you for your post. 
There is another oral medicament for SMA which crosses blood spinalcord barrier named Evrysdi. As you mentioned every cell has its own nucleus, so how do we expect Spinraza to help alternative splicing outside of spinal cord?

Comment: @kenn I don't understand your comment. Alternative splicing is a process that occurs at the nucleus. The nucleus of spinal motor neurons is located in the spinal cord, only the axons of those cells are found outside the spinal cord. We do not expect that alternative splicing is happening outside of the spinal cord for these cells because their cell bodies are not located outside of the spinal cord.

Comment: +1 For what it is worth, it might make sense to specify that it is intrathecally injected into the CSF, not the spinal cord itself. The drug can freely diffuse in the CSF into the brain/spinal chord parenchyma and reaches the motor neurons via this route: "In the adult the interface between the cerebrospinal fluid and the brain is lined by the ependymal cells, which are joined by gap junctions. These intercellular connections do not provide a diffusional restrain between the two compartments" (PMC4325900)